# C2061 for Win32 Application

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Win32 Programming. I have written a sample program as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdline, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello!!", "Message", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I get the following compile error:

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\propidl.h(327): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CAL'

`CAL` is the identifier for following struct in propidl.h

```
struct tagCAL
{
    ULONG cElems;
    /* [size_is] */ LONG *pElems;
}   CAL;
```

I have tried to reinstall Windows SDK, Visual Studio. But the issue is still there. However, this code is running on a different PC with same VS2012.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Did you install an extra Windows SDK? Is that causing the problem? The SDK shipped with VS2012 should not have this problem.

Comment: @WernerHenze : No I didn't install any other SDK.

Comment: @WernerHenze: I noticed a `Microsoft .NET Framework4.5 SDK` in my programs and features. Can this be an issue. When I uninstall, it gives a warning that other installed programs maybe using it.

Comment: I'd compare the include pathes on your both machines (working and not working). Maybe you see a difference that one machine gets the Windows SDK files from another SDK. You could also use compiler switch /P (or /EP) to write the output of the preprocessor to a file and compare that on both machines.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Both the include directories are same in both machines.